# data-link transform ? and = in hexadecimal

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angular

I have a problem.

In my professional project, in a .js file, a create a div with a button in, to associate this value to an object.

This is the way they "create" the button in my variable in the .js.

```
task.description = `
    <div>
      <button class="btn btn-warning btn-md m-b-s"
         data-link="/talent/vendors/${category._id}?category=${category.title}">
         START CHAT
      </button>
    </div>`;
```

In front, if a do a console log, my link is correct:

/talent/vendors/5679764aba9?category=Movers

instead of this, I've this when I click on the button: ( If a do a console log in my front, or even when a look in my inspector, the link is correct, it's doesn't work when I click on the button )

/talent/vendors/5679764aba9%3Fcategory%3DMovers

The '?' in the correct link is now '%3F' and the '=' is '%3D', in fact that change only these character by the hexadecimals value, and I don't understand why.

I don't know if what I'm saying is very understandable, so ask question if you need.

Comment: It's URL encoded values. Try whitespace ` ` will become `%20`

Answer (score 0):

This has been encoded, you can decode it with

```
decodeURI(YOURURL)
```

Have a look at;

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_encodeuri.asp

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_decodeuri.asp

Comment: In fact, the link is only encoded when I click on he button, not in the .js, so maybe I need to decode in my html page ?

Comment: Have you tried with the div only?     `<div *ngIf="task.description" [innerHtml]="task.description"></div>`

Comment: Yes and it doesn't work, if I do that, the button is not recognized

Answer (score 0):

I integrated my variable like this in my front

```
<div *ngIf="task.description" [innerHtml]="task.description | safehtml" routeDirective></div>
```

I think it's a this moment, with the innerHTML, it encode my link

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, I need to add a queryparams in this function, to force the decode of the URL, but I don't know what I need to write in this queryparams

```
export class routeDirective {

  constructor(private el: ElementRef, private router: Router) {}

  @HostListener('click', ['$event.target']) onClick($event) {
    const goRoute = $event.getAttribute('data-link');

    if (!!goRoute) {
      this.router.navigate([goRoute], {queryParams:});
    } 
  }

}
```